# can't use Hangfire with ASP.NET webforms Website

Tags: asp.net, hangfire

I have created empty asp.net webforms website using Visual studio 2013 from File > new > Website (not project ) and installed Hangfire library. then i have added Startup.cs File in App_code and root folder. then i have created simple test in Global.ascx file

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

        Hangfire.RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("I am done!"), Hangfire.Cron.Minutely);

    }
```

when i try to run the website, it returns

```
JobStorage.Current property value has not been initialized. You must set it before using Hangfire Client or Server API.
```

but if i create a project and do the same steps, it runs without any problem, anyone can help ?

Comment: looks like there is some trickery involved http://frankouimette.com/tutorial-installing-hangfire-without-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: can please post your solution? how it initialize Hangfire? and where it initialize  (in Global.asax)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  moved this line

```
Hangfire.RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("I am done, wasim!"), Hangfire.Cron.Minutely);
```

from Application_Start, i think he was calling it early, so i moved it to .aspx page.. and everything works well now!

Comment: if this solved your problem, why not choose it as accepted answer?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy it asked me to wait more minutes to accept it, then I forget to come back.. thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 0):

hello i have you some problem

so. you must remove this config

```
   <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="false" />
```

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```